# align* runaway error

Tags: errors, align

I have written the following code, and I have no idea what is wrong with it.

```
\begin{align*}
             L.H.S.&=  1+ \sum_{j=2}^{k+1} \frac{1}{j^2}\\
                   &= 1+ (\sum_{j=2}^{k} \frac{1}{j^2}) + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\\
                   &< \frac{1}{(k+1)^2)+2-\frac{1}{k} (by induction hypothesis)\\
                   &< 2- \frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} (because k\textgreater0)\\
                   &= 2-\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}\\
                   &< 2-\frac{k+1}{(k+1)^2}\\
                   &= 2-\frac{1}{k+1}\\ 
\end{align*}
```

I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
L.H.S.&= 1+ \sum _{j=2}^{k+1} \frac {1}{j^2}\\ &= 1+ (\sum _{j=2}^{k\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \align*.
```

Answer (score 2):

Runaway argument means you are missing a closing brace somewhere. In this case it's on the third line of your align where you have a `)` instead of `}` in `\frac{1}{(k+1)^2)`.

Also, as long as I'm here, for your explanation notes, you'll find the formatting is not what you want. I would suggest creating the following command:

```
\newcommand{\because}[1]{\quad\mbox{(#1)}}
```

which you can then use to write, e.g.,

```
      &< 2- \frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \because{because $k > 0$}\\
```

Comment: `\because` is defined in `amssymb.sty`, so it doesn't seem a good name.

Comment: @egreg I really need to get around to installing TeX on my system instead of relying on memory for all this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `\text` for explanations and further aligning them by adding two extra `&&`s.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\text{L.H.S.} 
  & = 1+ \sum_{j=2}^{k+1} \frac{1}{j^2}                   &&                                  \\
  & = 1+ \sum_{j=2}^{k} \frac{1}{j^2} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} &&                                  \\
  & < \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}+2-\frac{1}{k}                     && \text{(by induction hypothesis)} \\
  & < 2- \frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}                && \text{(because $k>0)$}           \\
  & = 2-\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}                                 &&                                  \\
  & < 2-\frac{k+1}{(k+1)^2}                               &&                                  \\
  & = 2-\frac{1}{k+1}                                     &&                                  \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or maybe the explanations in a smaller font size  (for instance \footnotesize, as semantically they're sort  of footnotes).

Comment: @Mico - Yes, I agree, the parentheses are not needed here.